# Find the points of a ndarray that fall inside another ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arcpy, laspy

I have created a NumPy structured array (called `arr`) with `arcpy` module doing:

```
arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray('MPtest','SHAPE@XYZ',explode_to_points=True)
```

The array looks like (only first rows are shown):

```
array([([309243.1420999998, 6143470.0293, 470.43829999999434],),
       ([309252.14080000017, 6143461.0857, 470.43829999999434],),
       ([309246.0201000003, 6143459.2754, 470.43829999999434],),
       ........................................................,
       ([309252.14080000017, 6143461.0857, 464.6000000000058],)], 
      dtype=[('SHAPE@XYZ', '<f8', (3,))])
```

It represents XYZ coordinates taken from the vertices of a 3d object (`'MPtest'`) built in ArcGIS (a `multipatch` geometry).

I have another NumPy array (generated from reading a `.las` file using the [`laspy`](https://github.com/laspy/laspy) module), called `point_cloud`. This array looks like:

```
[((30922713, 614349673, 46679, 154, 17, 1, -10, 79, 5,  11570.850892),)
 ((30922712, 614349659, 46674, 112, 17, 1, -10, 78, 5,  11570.850897),)
 ((30922709, 614349645, 46663, 161, 17, 1, -10, 77, 5,  11570.850902),),
 ..................................................................,)],
[('point', [('X', '<i4'), ('Y', '<i4'), ('Z', '<i4'), ('intensity', '<u2'), ('flag_byte', 'u1'), ('raw_classification', 'u1'), ('scan_angle_rank', 'i1'), ('user_data', 'u1'), ('pt_src_id', '<u2'), ('gps_time', '<f8')])]
```

I'd like to be able to possibly get the indices of the points of `point cloud` which fall within `arr`. Is this even possible?

I've been trying to play around with functions like [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), [`np.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html), [`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html), and finally [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html), but so far, I wasn't able to do that. Also, I have a quite robust background in Python, but still NumPy is kind of new and very complex to my eyes (at least at first sight...).

Comment: Define `fall inside` clearly.  What kinds of things have you tried? Using structured arrays may be making the task harder.

Comment: @hpaulj With `fall inside` I mean "the points of the point cloud that are inside the volume occupied by the 3d object". Also, I noticed that I can access the structured array like `arr['SHAPE@XYZ']` to obtain a "non-structured array", which might be easy to work with. Finally, I'll edit my question to include some tests I made as soon as possible. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Similarly `point_cloud['point']`, though its three fields should be changed to 3 columns of a 2d array.  I forget the correct use of `astype` or `view` for that task.  Check `scipy` for `qhull` functions.  I'm aware of them but haven't used them.

Comment: `pointcloud['point'][['X','Y','Z']].copy().view('3i')` to get a 2d 3 column array.

Comment: Thanks, the `pointcloud` becomes a 2d 3 columns array. I am now checking the [`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) function to see if I can implement it in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the unstructured arrays (as I see that you already achieve in comments) you can use [scipy.spatial.Delanuay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html#scipy.spatial.Delaunay) as follows:

I just create a sample box and some points to clarify the example:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

arr = np.array(list(product([0,1], repeat=3)))
arr
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
point_cloud = np.array([[0.5,0.5,0.5], [2,2,2]])
```

You then create the Delanuay Triangulation:

```
dt = Delaunay(arr)
```

And find wich points of point_cloud are inside dt (The Delanuay triangulation of arr):

```
points_inside_arr = dt.find_simplex(point_cloud) >=0
points_inside_arr
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

This results in a numpy boolean array indicating which of the points in point cloud are inside arr.

Comment: Wow thanks! I'll try that tomorrow and tell you about my progress. Will also learn what "simplices" are...

Comment: Just a fancy word for n-dimensional triangles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex

Comment: That worked perefctly! Thank you again, really apreciate!

Comment: Glad to help you